# Debugging pypi packaging: pip install succeeds, but ModuleNotFound on import

Tags: python, pypi

I've packaged together a library and uploaded to Pypi. Pip install works but import gives "module not found" error, any suggestions how to debug?

```
pip install autograd_lib .       # works
python -c "import autograd_lib"  # ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'autograd_lib'
```

Comment: I assume you meant python -c ?
Have you verified the library is installed where you think it is for the version of Python you are running?

Comment: I don't think it's an issue of local env, just tried `pip install autograd_lib` on a brand new box, same issue

Comment: I just pip installed it myself and the site-packages has the dist-info folder but not the actual library.

Comment: The output of `pip show --files autograd_lib` will show what files have been actually installed. If it doesn't look right, then show how the project is being packaged (`setup.py`, `setup.cfg`, or `pyproject.toml`).

Answer (score 3):

Your [`autograd_lib/`](https://github.com/cybertronai/autograd-lib/tree/44af6717dce504d318f511d1cf476e331e6015d2/autograd_lib) subdirectory doesn't have file `__init__.py` hence `setuptools.find_packages()` doesn't consider it as a package so `setuptools` doesn't include it in the archives.

Simply create an empty file `__init__.py` in the directory, increase version and create a new release.